# Parsing string fragments in ANTLR4

Tags: java, antlr4

I have a grammar which expresses instructions for creating data structures including text, which are nested inside other instructions expressing under what circumstances the data structures should be created.  It is processed using a visitor rather than a listener.  Sometimes, the text can be very long and for formatting, splitting it across lines will make it easier to read.

For example:

```
store(martin-luther-king,
      "The ultimate measure of a man is not where he stands in moments of comfort"
      " and convenience, but where he stands at times of challenge and controversy.")
```

is easier to read than

```
   store(martin-luther-king,"The ultimate measure of a man is not
where he stands in moments of comfort and convenience, but where he
stands at times of challenge and controversy.")
```

This style of splitting strings is familiar to Python coders. To accomplish this, my grammar contains:

```
quotedString : STRING+ ;
STRING : DOUBLEQUOTE (~["\\\r\n] | ('\\' .))+ DOUBLEQUOTE ;
WS : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
fragment DOUBLEQUOTE : '"' ;
```

and generally works well.

While parsing a grammar which inadvertently contained something like:

```
"I did not" "" "speak out"
```

where a *quotedString* rule was expected, lexing/parsing failed with a java.lang.ClassCastException reporting "DocGenLexer cannot be cast to org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser".  I believe it would be more appropriate for this to fail with the exception that reports "no viable alternative".

My code (after in-lining a method, for the sake of brevity) looks like:

```
    String docGen = "store(martin-luther-king,\"I did not\" \"\" \"speak out\")";
    DocGenLexer lexer = new DocGenLexer(CharStreams.fromString(docGen));
    lexer.removeErrorListeners();
    lexer.addErrorListener(DocGenErrorListener.INSTANCE);

    TokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

    DocGenParser parser = new DocGenParser(tokenStream);
    parser.removeErrorListeners();
    parser.addErrorListener(DocGenErrorListener.INSTANCE);

    ParseTree parseTree = parser.docGen();
```

I would like to correct this, and I originally assumed this represents a deficiency of my grammar (rather than a bug in ANTLR4), but have discovered the problem is in the error listener class.

Code for error listener :

```
public class DocGenErrorListener extends BaseErrorListener {

    public static final DocGenErrorListener INSTANCE = new DocGenErrorListener();

    @Override
    public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer,
                            Object offendingSymbol,
                            int line, int charPositionInLine,
                            String msg,
                            RecognitionException e) throws ParseCancellationException {
        // the following line is the origin of the problem
        List<String> stack = ((Parser) recognizer).getRuleInvocationStack();
        Collections.reverse(stack);
        throw new DocGenParseException(
        String.format("rule stack: %s\nline %d:%d at %s: %s",
                stack, line, charPositionInLine, offendingSymbol, msg));
    }
}
```

Should I conclude that I need a different error listener classes for errors generated by the lexer and parser?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include enough code so that others can reproduce this error?

Comment: @Bart Kiers: I have done so, while omitting (what are hopefully non-germane) portions of the grammar in the interest of brevity.  With the empty string "" removed, it works correctly.  If my sample is inadequate, I can add missing portions of the grammar.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, but it is incomplete, and will also not compile (`String docGen = ...` will throw a compile time error). Others need to copy and paste your grammar and Java code and when running it, should be able to see the error/exception you describe.

Comment: @BartKiers Thanks, and apologies for my being slow in correcting that.  The code is buried inside a large project and I had a lot of work to do elsewhere.  I have discovered where the problem lies (the error listener class) and updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem. Your grammar does not allow for empty strings.

```
"I did not" "" "speak out"
```

contains a string saying "I did not", and empty string, and a string saying "speak out", you should change the lexer rule to say:

```
STRING : DOUBLEQUOTE (~["\\\r\n] | ('\\' .))* DOUBLEQUOTE ;
```

Comment: You have a point, but it does not explain the OP's `ClassCastException`.

Comment: that's true, from the error message posted it seems they are trying to cast their lexer into a parser. I'm honestly unsure of how mixed grammar files work because I always separate them to take advantage of lexical modes.